# mpc autostart and play url 3 systemd

Tags: daemon, music, music-player

Contents of `/etc/systemd/system/mpc.autostart.service`

```
[Unit] Description=Music Player Client-Auto Start-Agent

[Service] Type=forking ExecStart=/usr/bin/mpd start && /usr/bin/mpc start && /usr/bin/mpc play 3 ExecReload=/usr/bin/mpd start && /usr/bin/mpc start && /usr/bin/mpc play 3 ExecStop=/usr/bin/mpd stop && /usr/bin/mpc stop RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install] WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Contents of `/usr/bin/mpc.autostart`

```
start() {    
   exec usr/bin/mpc start    
   exec usr/bin/mpc play 3 
}

stop() {      
   exec usr/bin/mpc stop 
}

case $1 in  start|stop) "$1" ;;esac
```

I have also ran:

```
sudo systemctl enable mpc.autostart.service

Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mpc.autostart.service to 

/etc/systemd/system/mpc.autostart.service.
```

However it fails to run.

```
systemctl

lightdm.service           loaded active     running         Light Display Mana 
mpc.autostart.service     loaded failed     failed          Music Player Clien  
mpd-autoplay.service      loaded active     exited          LSB: Ensures that        
mpd.service               loaded active     running         Music Player Daemo
```

Comment: Hi there, now I have finished with the mpc client, because it don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm now finished with the mpc client because this works not immensely.

Now I'm using the VLC 2.2.1 Terry Pratchett and I stream only contens via http://

kind regards